# Direct download & install into iphone/ipad in C#

Tags: c#

I want to create a download and install ipa file automatically function in to iphone/ipad in C# ?But i have no idea how to do it.I only use a command way to download the file but it wont install into my iphone/ipad automatically?Is that possible do in C#?

It wrong code just an ideal for it:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filePath = string.Empty;
        string appType = string.Empty;


        //ios
        filePath = "appFile/Apps.ipa";
        appType = "application/octet-stream";

      Response.ClearContent();
      Response.ContentType = MimeType(Path.GetExtension(fName),appType);
      Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename = {0}",System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fName)));
      Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", sz.ToString("F0"));
      Response.TransmitFile(fName);
      Response.End();


    }
    public static string MimeType(string Extension,string appMineType)
    {
        string mime = appMineType;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Extension))
            return mime;
        string ext = Extension.ToLower();
        Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey rk = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(ext);
        if (rk != null && rk.GetValue("Content Type") != null)
            mime = rk.GetValue("Content Type").ToString();
        return mime;
    }
```

Comment: To install an IPA to an iDevice, you have to add the UDID to provisioning profile, not just download the IPA to the device.

Comment: what is UDID got any reference?

Comment: @user1511029 - Can you phrase that question in a way it actually makes sense?

Comment: Another potentially very useful yet completely lazily written question.

Comment: UDID is a unique device identifier .